# can i have multiple methods executing at the same time?

Tags: java

All what i want is to execute three methods or more at the same time

I don't mean Threads because i have tried threads but it just execute one method at a time

```
public void run() {
  System.out.println("Running " +  threadName );
  try {
     for(int i = 4; i > 0; i--) {
        System.out.println("Thread: " + threadName + ", " + i);
        // Let the thread sleep for a while.
        Thread.sleep(50);
     }
  }catch (InterruptedException e) {
     System.out.println("Thread " +  threadName + " interrupted.");
  }
  System.out.println("Thread " +  threadName + " exiting.");
```

}

in this code one method will execute and then sleeps waiting for the execution of another method

but what i want is to make the three methods execute at the same time.

is it possible? and if it is how can i do it and from where to start?

Comment: How many CPUs does your computer have?  If it's only one, then it can only do one thing at a time.  Otherwise "threads" is in fact the correct answer to your question.

Comment: @DavidWallace - Even on a single-core, single-CPU machine, Java threads do a pretty good job of simulating multiple, simultaneous paths of execution.

Comment: @TedHopp I agree.  Perhaps I'm interpreting the question far too literally.

Comment: @DavidWallace multi-core systems support many operations at a time i think

Comment: And the correct answer is .... threads.  I'm wondering what you might have been doing wrong to convince yourself that threads don't work.

Comment: @DavidWallace no you missed understanding me , Threads work fine but depending on the case .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have tried threads, but it sounds like you didn't try them correctly if each method runs by itself. Try something like this:

```
public static void someMethod(int i) {
    String me = Thread.currentThread().getName();
    Random r = new Random();
    while (i-- >= 0) {
        System.out.println(me + ": i=" + i);
        try {
            // sleep some random time between 50 and 150 ms
            Thread.sleep(r.nextInt(100) + 50);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(me + " interrupted");
            return;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(me + " exiting");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numThreads = 4;
    for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; ++i) {
        new Thread("Thread " + i) {
            @Override public void run() { someMethod(10); }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

You'll see the output from `someMethod` for all the threads mixed up together. And it should be different every time you run the code.